# regex replace for multiple string array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, replace

I have a array of string and the patterns like `#number-number` anywhere inside a string.

**Requirements**:

- If the # and single digit number before by hyphen then replace #  and add 0. For example, `#162-7878` => `162-7878`, `#12-4598866` => `12-4598866`
- If the # and two or more digit number before by hyphen then replace remove #. For example,  `#1-7878` => `01-7878`.
- If there is no # and single digit number before by hyphen then add 0. For example, `1-7878` => `01-7878`.

I got stuck and how to do in JavaScript. Here is the **code I used**:

```js
let arrstr=["#12-1676","#02-8989898","#676-98908098","12-232","02-898988","676-98098","2-898988", "380100 6-764","380100 #6-764","380100 #06-764"]

for(let st of arrstr)
 console.log(st.replace(/#?(\d)?(\d-)/g ,replacer))
 
 function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string){
  let replaceSubString = p1 || "0";
  replaceSubString += p2;
  return replaceSubString;
 }
```

Comment: remove the #? and change it to # and your all good!

Comment: please edit your question

Comment: @SolomonPByer thanks for reply, updated the question

Comment: `.replace(/^#?(\d+)(?=-\d)/, (_,$1) => $1.padStart(2,"0"))`  [seems working well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707846/3832970) enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest matching `#` optionally at the start of string, and then capture one or more digits before `-` + a digit to later pad those digits with leading zeros and omit the leading `#` in the result:

```js
st.replace(/#?\b(\d+)(?=-\d)/g, (_,$1) => $1.padStart(2,"0"))
```

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
let arrstr=["#12-1676","#02-8989898","#676-98908098","12-232","02-898988","676-98098","2-898988", "380100 6-764","380100 #6-764","380100 #06-764"]

for(let st of arrstr)
 console.log(st,'=>', st.replace(/#?\b(\d+)(?=-\d)/g, (_,$1) => $1.padStart(2,"0") ))
```

The `/#?\b(\d+)(?=-\d)/g` regex matches all occurrences of

- `#?` - an optional `#` char
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits...
- `(?=-\d)` - that must be followed with a `-` and a digit (this is a positive lookahead that only checks if its pattern matches immediately to the right of the current location without actually consuming the matched text).

Comment: thanks for helping , `#6-764 78798` should be `06-764 78798` but returns same

Comment: @sen It returns `#6-764 78798 => 06-764 78798`

Comment: apologies `78798 #6-764` should be `78798 06-764` but returns same

Comment: the above code does not work for `380100 6-764, 380100 #6-764, 380100 #06-764` for these should return `380100 06-764`

Comment: `let arrstr=["#12-1676","#02-8989898","#676-98908098","12-232","02-898988","676-98098","2-898988", "380100 6-764","380100 #6-764","380100 #06-764"]` last three string pattern does not working,

Comment: @sen I had a meeting with my manager. All you need is a word boundary, not a start of string anchor.

Comment: Stribiżews sorry to disturb and thanks a lot for helping,

Comment: @sen It's my pleasure. I only missed the "anywhere inside a string" bit. If you have problems with the word boundary, replace with `(?<!\d)`. Or let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`unary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), here's a two liner `replacer` function.

```js
const testValues = ["#162-7878", "#12-4598866", "#1-7878", "1-7878"];
const re = /#?(\d+?)-(\d+)/;

for(const str of testValues) {
  console.log(str.replace(re, replacer));
}

function replacer(match, p1, p2) {
  p1 = +p1 < 10 ? `0${p1}` : p1;
  return `${p1}-${p2}`; 
}
```

Comment: hanks for helping but when i pass 1-7878 should be 01-7878

Comment: @sen Adjusted answer.

Comment: thanks for reply again but its not working for `#02-7878` changes to `002-7878` instead of `02-7878`

Comment: @sen You posted some code in the question: is it  working fine for you? If yes, what do you need?

Comment: thanks for reply, `this scenario ->string like "2-7878" to "02-7878" works` when i try #02-7878 its not working, it shows 002-7878 instead of 02-7878 .

Answer (score 0):

```
let list_of_numbers =["#1-7878", "#162-7878", "#12-1676","#02-8989898","#676-98908098","12-232","02-898988","676-98098","2-898988"]

const solution = () => {
    let result = ''
    for (let number of list_of_numbers) {
        let nums = number.split('-')
        if (nums[0][0] == '#' && nums[0].length > 2) {
            result = `${nums[0].slice(1, number.length-1)}-${nums[1]}`
            console.log(result)
        } else if (nums[0][0] == '#' && nums[0].length == 2) {
            result = `${nums[0][0] = '0'}${nums[0][1]}-${nums[1]}`
            console.log(result)
        } else {
            console.log(number)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple check is what you should do with the match function.

```js
let arrstr=["#12-1676","#0-8989898","#676-98908098","12-232","02-898988","676-98098","2-898988"];
const regex = /#\d-/g;
for(i in arrstr){
    var found = arrstr[i].match(regex);
    if(found){
      arrstr[i]=arrstr[i].replace("#","0")
    }else{
      arrstr[i]=arrstr[i].replace("#","")
    }
}
console.log(arrstr);
```

or if you really want to stick with the way you have it.

```js
let arrstr=["#12-1676","#02-8989898","#6-98908098","12-232","02-898988","676-98098","2-898988"]

for(let st of arrstr)
 console.log(st.replace(/#(\d)?(\d-)/g ,replacer))
 
 function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string){
  let replaceSubString = p1 || "0";
  replaceSubString += p2;
  return replaceSubString;
 }
```

remove the '?' from the regex so its not #? but just #

Comment: thanks but when i pass `2-898988` should be `02-898988`

Comment: then what isn't working about your code?

Comment: It works, but if there is no # and single digit  before by hyphen, add only 0, not working, updated the question, apologies for missing out, thanks for helping